# Choosing Colored Ball, probability of second choice not knowing first

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 50 balls in an urn, 30 are red and 20 are blue. If a single ball is taken and we don't look at its color, what is the probability that the second ball is red?

I know that there is a 60% chance of choosing a red ball from the first choice, and 40% of not. That means for the second ball there is either (29 choose 1)/(49 choose 1) 60% of the time or (30 choose 1)/(49 choose 1) 40% of the time. I then multiplied the probabilities (60% and 40%) by each of the options and got a 60% chance of the second ball being red. Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: This is correct and one among many correct ways of looking at the problem, but it is an *incredibly tedious* way.  If you were asked to run the same calculations for if you pull forty-nine of the balls out without looking and ask what the probability the final ball is red, you will again arrive at the probability of $0.6$.  You will not want to use the same approach in proving this however as it would seemingly require mapping out all $\binom{50}{30}\approx 4.7\cdot 10^{13}$ orders in which you can draw blue vs red balls.

Comment: The much more elegant approach is in recognizing that the position in the sequence that you draw is completely irrelevant.  To formalize this, you can assert that there is a convenient bijection between the scenarios of pulling the first ball but *calling* it the "$i$'th ball" and then drawing the rest and labeling them appropriately (*or indeed by labeling the balls in any arbitrary order*) versus pulling out the balls and labeling them in the usual order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any of the $50$ balls is equally likely to be the second ball drawn. The probability that this second ball is red therefore is ${3\over5}$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your solution is correct.

Here is another way of looking at the problem:

If we select the balls without replacement one by one, we create a sequence of $50$ balls, where the $k$th ball in the sequence is the $k$th ball selected.  Of these $50$ balls, $30$ are red.  Since the balls are randomly selected, a red ball is equally likely to be anywhere in the sequence.  Hence, the probability that a red ball will be in the $k$th position of the sequence is 
$$\frac{30}{50} = \frac{3}{5}$$
which means the probability that the $k$th ball selected from the urn is also $3/5$.  In particular, the probability that the second ball selected from the urn is red is $3/5$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your solution is correct. However, the problem statement doesn't explicitly state that we don't replace the balls, but we will make that assumption.

If the first ball is red with probability $\frac{30}{50}$ then the second ball is red with probability $\frac{29}{49}$

If the first ball is blue with probability $\frac{20}{50}$ then the second ball is red with probability $\frac{30}{49}$

All together, we get

$$\frac{30}{50}\cdot \frac{29}{49}+\frac{20}{50}\cdot \frac{30}{49}=0.6$$

which agrees with your solution.

Comment: "*A simpler approach*"  Your approach is the exact same as the OP's with the minor exception that you chose to write $29$ instead of $\binom{29}{1}$ and $49$ instead of $\binom{49}{1}$ etc... hardly a noticeable improvement.  The method will not generalize well either, e.g. for calculating if the twentieth ball is red.

Comment: You're right, I have edited my answer.

Comment: By symmetry, _unconditional_ probabilities $P(R_1) = P(R_2) = 30/50.$

Comment: Thanks, I’m glad I had figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

Possible outcomes for drawing two balls (without replacement) are Blue(1st) and Red (2nd) or Red (1st) and Red (2nd)

$P(BR\ or\  RR)=P(BR)+P(RR)- P(BR \cap RR)= \frac{20}{50}\times\frac{30}{49}+\frac{30}{50}\times\frac{29}{49}-0 = \frac{1470}{2450}=0.6$

Answer (score 2):

Note:
$$P(R_1\cap R_2)+P(B_1\cap R_2)=P((R_1\cap R_2)\cup (B_1\cap R_2))=\\
=P((R_1\cup B_1)\cap R_2)=P(R_2).$$
Also note:
$$P(R_1\cap R_2)+P(B_1\cap R_2)=P(R_1\cap R_2)+P(R_1\cap B_2)=\\
P((R_1\cap R_2)\cup (R_1\cap B_2))=P(R_1\cap(R_2\cup B_2))=P(R_1).$$